# Accessing local https site over LAN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I am trying to debug my `ASP.Net MVC` website when hosted over `https`. I am hosting this via the `IIS` instance with Visual Studio. I need to access the website from a mobile device - so I am attempting to access the site via LAN.

I have enabled https via visual studio by going to the project properties and setting `SSL Enabled` to `true`. Now, when I debug the site, it starts two local instances; one for `http` (as usual) and one for `https`. The internal ports for these are listed when I right click the `IIS` icon in the task tray.

I do not have an SSL certificate installed. My browser gives me insecure connection warnings, but I just dismiss them - I don't believe these are a concern as I am just testing locally (I could be wrong).

I am using a program called Sharp Proxy to translate these internal ports to external ones, allowing my site to be accessible. `64312` is my internal port for accessing the site over http. Sharp proxy is translating this to `4567`. `44300` is my internal port for accessing the site over https. Sharp proxy is translating this to `5678`.

Successful permutations:

```
http://localhost:64312 - SUCCESS
https://localhost:44300 - SUCCESS
http://192.168.0.72:4567 - SUCCESS
```

Failed permutations:

```
https://192.168.0.72:5678 - FAIL
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
```

The issue is clearly not to do with accessing my machine over LAN as I am able to successfully hit `192.168.0.72` with `http`.

**My question is: What do I need to do to be able to access my `https` site over LAN via debugging with Visual Studio?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to verify the identity of the server you're connecting to, HTTPS needs a hostname to check the certificate against.

Therefore, you cannot connect to an IP address over HTTPS.

You need to use a domain name.

Comment: Thank you. What's the simplest way of setting one up locally?

Comment: @BrianButterfield Use your host file in windows and assign an IP address a hostname.